# Seemingly random performance drops on Pop!_OS

Tags: performance, pop-os, malware, lag

I am sure many PC users have experienced slow downs on their computers over time (mine is about a year old), but this scenario I find strange.

**The Problem**

At about 5:30PM yesterday I was browsing the web and running commands (mainly trying to change my background in a shell script). I had a few different web pages open when I noticed huge amounts of lag. I tried closing all windows and nothing changed. I could tell by moving my mouse across the screen that it would freeze for a small period of time every second. I assumed a restart would handle it, but the lag persisted.

The next day I started my PC and everything seemed normal, but after opening a few windows the lag started again. I noticed it started and stopped randomly, sometimes happening right when I booted and it would even go away sometimes. This is when I started to try and find the problem.

**Possible causes**

1. The last thing I can remember doing before the lag is running `# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/jonas/Pictures/dark-wallpaper.jpeg`. This command did not work (I was trying to change the background).
2. A bit earlier I tried to install banshee by adding the repository `# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa`. This threw an error so I removed the repository with the `-r` option. I also tried to install 'lyrebird' with `# sudo dpkg -i lyrebird_1.1.0-3.deb` which I had downloaded from Github. Both attempts were unsuccessful.

**What I've tried**

1. Run clamscan on my home directory folder (0 viruses detected)
2. Check system monitor for possible resource intensive programs. I compared a screenshot of it when lag wasn't happening and when it was, there were no differences.

I doubt anyone will be able to give me an exact cause, but even just a suggestion on how to find the problem will mean a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the problem. It seems like for whatever reason my GPU (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti) suddenly decided it wasn't going to run at any temperature above 52 degrees Celsius. While I still have no solution (other than increasing the fan speed, and I will probably try and clean it out), it is relieving to know the problem.

EDIT: I ended up just taking out my GPU, dusting it off, and plugging it back in. It works just fine now, maybe the issue was just dust buildup. :/